# InvalidOperationException while saving a new model object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, entity-framework-6

I am trying to add a new `User` (model) which includes a `Role` (model).
My view includes a `DropDownListFor` which contains a list of roles.
I am always getting an exception when trying to finally add the user to the database.

#### View:

```
@model Keba.Data.EF.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add User";
    List<SelectListItem> roles = new List<SelectListItem>();

}
<h2>Add</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "User", FormMethod.Post,
                                      new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr><th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)</th><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)</td></tr>
        <tr><th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)</th><td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)</td></tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MailAdress)
        <tr>
            <th>Roles</th>
            <td>
               @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Role.RoleId, new SelectList(ViewBag.roles, "RoleId", "RoleName"))

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="add" type="submit" value="add" />
    <input name="cancel" type="submit" value="cancel" />
}
```

#### Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddUser(User user)
 {
     if (Request.Form["add"] != null)
     {
         user.Role = RoleModel.Instance.getRoles().Where(x => x.RoleId == user.Role.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
         UserModel.Instance.AddUser(user);
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

#### Model:

```
public void AddUser(User user)
{
    using(var db = new KebaContext())
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.MailAdress = "";
            db.UserSet.Add(user);//Exception
            db.SaveChanges();
        }             
    }
}
```

#### Exception:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyContextForAddOrAttach(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
   at .....
```

Comment: How have you defined `Role`s and `User`s? There isn't any 1-1 relationships?

Comment: They are defined 1-*, they were created with a model designer (entity framework) http://imgur.com/5kuTrMJ

Comment: Any chance you can get this up on github so we debug this problem a little better?

Comment: Are both the RoleModel and the UserModel sharing the same database context? This error can be happen when the entities are not sharing the same DB context but you're taking the object from one context and attempting to use it on the other (applying the role to the user).

Answer (score 0):

In the model's `AddUser`, you're creating a new `KebaContext` and adding `user`, but `user.Role` looks like it contains a `Role` from a different context.

Comment: there is no other context, just KebaContext.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is that it looks like you're retrieving a `Role` from one instance of `KebaContext` (in `getRoles()`?), then when you add user, you're adding it to a new instance of `KebaContext`, which attempts to attach any associated entities to that context. You might need to make sure the previous context has been disposed.